# sending a sequence of goals to move_base

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a mobile robot which is navigating around a room and it can go from start to goal without any issues. Now, I want to send a sequence of goals to [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) so that once the robot reaches its first goal, it automatically starts moving to its second goal and so on. One way which I can think of is to send a second goal when the robot reaches its first goal but how can I know that the robot has reached its first goal automatically? Does it publish anything on any topic once it reaches the goal or is any flag set or changed? Does anyone have any idea about how can it be done or is there a better way to send a sequence of goals to move_base so that the robot just keeps on going from one goal to another?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210987/sending-a-sequence-of-goals-to-move_base/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use the [Action API](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Action_API) of move_base.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Progtologist](https://answers.ros.org/users/11081/progtologist/) on 2015-06-10**:
Or read the [appropriate tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals)

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-06-10**:
Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-05-28**:
can you please give information how you coped with this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I modified the famous tutorial that sends goal to move_base. The code sends 5 different goals sequantially. Hope this helps

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
    #include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseAction.h>
    #include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>
    
    typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> MoveBaseClient;
    
    int x [5] = { 1, 2, 2, 4, 4}; 
    int y [5] = {0, 0 ,2 , 2, 4};
    
    int lenght0f_Array = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);
    
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
      ros::init(argc, argv, "simple_navigation_goals");
    
      //tell the action client that we want to spin a thread by default
      MoveBaseClient ac("move_base", true);
    
      //wait for the action server to come up
      while(!ac.waitForServer(ros::Duration(5.0))){
        ROS_INFO("Waiting for the move_base action server to come up");
      }
    
      move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal;
    
      //we'll send a goal to the robot to move 1 meter forward
      goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "base_link";
      goal.target_pose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
      for( int i = 0; i < lenght0f_Array; i = i + 1 ) {
     
       
        goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = x[i];
        goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = y[i];
      ROS_INFO("Sending goal");
      ac.sendGoal(goal);
    
      ac.waitForResult();
    
      if(ac.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED)
        ROS_INFO("Hooray, the base moved 1 meter forward");
      else
        ROS_INFO("The base failed to move forward 1 meter for some reason");
       }
       
    
      return 0;
    }
```

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2018-05-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-06**:
hello, when I tried your code, i got the following error:

error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-16**:
I have directed the question [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/294298/sending-multiple-goals-to-sendingsimplegoals/)

**Comment by [kurshakuz](https://answers.ros.org/users/42874/kurshakuz/) on 2019-07-14**:
Hi! Isn't it your for loop is just overwriting the same variable and in the end ActionClient simply sends location 5 meters away? What is the purpose of this code?

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2019-10-17**:
@kurshakuz what 5 meter ? and 5 meter in which axis ?